# Placing HTML input fields in my PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, forms

I made a simple website for myself, and now that i'm coming to and end of finishing it up. I've come across the following problem.

I made a form which i want in an array. This is what the input fields looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td>Pizza Margherita</td>
    <td>&#8364; 7.00</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="countMargherita" class="formnumbers" name="PizzaMargherita" onChange="validateForm(this);changeTotalFromCount(this);" min="1" max="99" data-unitprice="7"/></td>
    <td><span id="totalMargherita"></span></td>
</tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N3EBz/

But i have 11 of those products so you can understand my form is a bit messy. And if i needed to add more products it would be a real pain to add them like this.

I decided to put them inside an array but i'm a little confused as to how i should do that.

And how exactly do I take the array and let it echo out on the page this form gets send to?

Thanks in advance!

If yo uneed any clarification please tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create array with product arrays inside

```
$productsData = array(
    array(
       'code' => 'margherita',
       'name'=> 'Pizza Margherita',
       'price' => '7.00'
    ),
    array(
       'code' => 'withmeat',
       'name'=> 'Pizza with meat',
       'price' => '10.00'
       'field_name' => 'PizzaMargherita'
    )
);

<?php foreach($productsData as $productData):?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $productData['name']?></td>
    <td>&#8364; <?php echo $productData['price']?></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="count<?php echo $productData['code']?>" class="formnumbers" name="<?php echo $productData['code']?>" onChange="validateForm(this);changeTotalFromCount(this);" min="1" max="99" data-unitprice="7"/></td>
     <td><span id="total<?php echo $productData['code']?>"></span></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly how I wanted it, needed a little customization for my needs but this example helped me so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into loops and iterative output. Output via a PHP array is one means; client-side templating engines are another. They both equate to the same concept of iterative output.

Simple PHP example:

```
<?php
$arr = array('product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3');
foreach($arr as $product) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $product; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I know this bit of php array but is there a way i can place the input fields inside one as well. Since all of them are exactly the same, except where id, name and data-unitprice change per product. I'm nowhere near experienced in PHP so i'm trying all the possibilities.

Comment: It would be bad design to store your HTML in the array. Work instead with the methodology of segregating your data from your output. Store in the array just the data, then build the HTML in the iterative code, i.e. in this case the loop body.